# Why functions in Golang are pointers

Tags: go, pointers, func

In the GoLang we can divide all data types into two groups.

Int, Float, Array, Strucs - value types
Slice, Map, Func, Interface - pointer types.

I understand why Slice and Map are pointers. For example you can add more values into the map in the different function:

```
func main() {
    m := make(map[string]string)
    updateMap(m)
    fmt.Println(m)
}

func updateMap(m map[string]string) {
    m["1"] = "1"
    m["2"] = "2"
    m["3"] = "3"
    m["4"] = "4"
}
```

Slice you can simply update:

```
func main() {
   s := make([]int, 2)
   s[0] = 0
   s[1] = 0

   updateSlice(s)
   fmt.Println(s)
}

func updateSlice(s []int) {
   s[0] = 1
   s[1] = 1
}
```

**But what is the reason for func to be a pointer? **

I can't overwrite it:

```
func main() {
 f := func() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
 }

 update(f)
 f()

}

func update(f func()) {
 f = func() {
  fmt.Println(2)
 }
}
```

So, i really confused why it should be a pointer, why it can't be just an value?

I have an assumption, that this is related to memory managment of the functions.
IMHO, if funcs wount be a pinters, we could not do like this:

```
func main() {
   s := 2
   x := func() {
      s = 3
   }
   updateFunc(x)
   fmt.Println(s)
}

func updateFunc(f func()) {
   f()
}
```

Comment: Neither maps nor slices "are pointers". Functions are pointers neither. Some things have reference semantics, namely slices, maps, buffered channels and functions closures.

Comment: In addition to what Volker and Peter have said (Go has only two pointer types: `*T`, with `T` being any other type, and `unsafe.Pointer`), there's a perfect reason for a function or a method to have pointer semantics: a function contains code to be executed, and that code is 1) necessarily _located_ somewhere in memory, and 2) there is no sense to literally copy that code when you assign a value of function/method type to a variable—since functions are immutable in Go; it's way more sensible to copy the address (note that method values are more complex: they need to remember receivers).

Comment: I have tried to address that "value vs reference semantics" breakdown here on SO; you might find it worth reading. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20856597/720999) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72979409/720999).

Answer (score 3):

Functions are not pointers and neither are slices, maps, nor interfaces. Pointers can be dereferenced, but none of the other types can be. Slices and maps are data structures that *contain* pointers, that's all.

Your updateMap and updateSlice functions are invalid analogies to `update(f func())` because they don't assign to the argument. Try for instance:

```
func updateSlice(s []int) {
   s = []int{}
}
```

[In Go, all arguments are passed by value:](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Calls)

> After [the function value and arguments] are evaluated, the parameters of the call are passed by value to the function and the called function begins execution.