# What is going on under the hood with these structs? Will struct be copied?

Tags: go, pointers, memory

I'm not uderstanding what is really going on in this piece of code.

The receiver func works on original struct User (because of pointer), so inside of func we changing the original obj. But will the struct address also be original or it will be copy of original 'a'?

```
func main() {
    a := Address{"Freedom", "Kyiv"}
    u := User{"Valeriy", "Zalyzhnyi", a}
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(u)
    u.updateStreet("Peremohy")

    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(u)
}

func (u *User) updateStreet(street string) {
    u.address.street = street
}

type User struct {
    firstName string
    lastName  string
    address   Address
}

type Address struct {
    street string
    city   string
}
```

This is my output

```
{Freedom Kyiv}
{Valeriy Zalyzhnyi {Freedom Kyiv}}
{Freedom Kyiv}
{Valeriy Zalyzhnyi {Peremohy Kyiv}}
```

From this I understand that u.address is changed, also I see that this 'a' inside of 'u' is different obj from the original one.
So what exactly is going on under the hood and in memory?
Based on the output this behavior for me is completely unexpected.
I was expecting that because of the pointer we work with the original object in both cases ('a' and 'u'). And the second (after func 'update..') printing of fmt.Println(a) will give us {Peremohy Kyiv} because the second fmt.Println(u) gave us {Valeriy Zalyzhnyi {Peremohy Kyiv}}

Comment: As you expected, you should use a pointer (*Address)  in `User` struct. Take a look here. https://go.dev/play/p/QWZwgQin0T2

Comment: `address Address` means the field `address` has the type `Address`, and that means all the fields of `Address` are contained "in place" of `address` in the enclosing `User`—as if you would do something like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/sf1TZHzz002) (which is valid code, BTW). In other words, variables of type `User` do not _reference_ variables of type `Address`, but contain their fields directly.

Comment: Because in Go, assign will work as a "value copy". If you use a pointer field, it will assign to your u as a pointer value, `u.address` and `&a` both point to the same obj

Comment: @spike014 Does this declaration [link](https://go.dev/play/p/QWZwgQin0T2) will be proper in production code ? I mean using pointers to internal structs inside of top-level struct ?

Comment: If you want to change `u.address` when `a` changed, it will be a familiar way to do this. But you should make sure the obj like `a` won't be changed somewhere you DO NOT know. @RostyslavKholodnytskyi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what happens *under the hood*, it can be useful to visualise what your code does:

```
a = address{}
u := user{address: a}
```

breaks down to this:

```
| variable value        | memory address |
| a = address{}         | 0x000001       |
| u = user{}            | 0x000002       |
| u.address = copy of a | 0x000003       |
```

So you have allocated memory for 1 instance of `user{}`, and 2 instances of `address{}`. The value of the second address instance is an exact copy of the first, at the point when the copy was created.

Now when you call `updateStreet`, it is invoked on `u` through a pointer, it doesn't create a copy of the `user` instance, but rather operates on the memory address `0x000002`, so effectively it operates on the same `a` variable. Therefore the expression:

```
u.address.street = "foo"
```

Translates to something like: on the value held in memory address 0x000002, access the field called `address`, in that field, access the field `street` and assign it the new value. Let's map this on to the table we have created above:

```
  0x000002 -> address (which is stored in 0x000003)
              |
              --> set street to "foo"
```

Once the function returns, we still have the same objects as before, in the same location in memory, but because we've accessed the value of `a` through its address in memory, the changes made by the `updateStreet` function have been made to the value of `u` (because we used the same memory address).

The variable `a` was **copied** in the assignment to `u.address`, so its memory address wasn't known to, or passed on to the `updateStreet` function, and therefore remains unchanged.

Comment: So, if I will write production code, do I have to prefer using a pointer to the internal struct (in this case Address) or not?

Comment: @RostyslavKholodnytskyi, your question, as stated, has no sense: whether to use a pointer or not does not depend on the code to be written being "of production quality" or not ("toy examples"); whether to use a pointer or not should be judged on a case-by-case basis, there's no "just always to it that way" rule. Most of the time, you should use a pointer if the variable pointed to by that pointer should exist as a single instance (and referred to from multiple places)…

Comment: @RostyslavKholodnytskyi, …. I have tried to explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72979409/720999) a very similar case of storing values vs pointers to variables containing such values in slices. Slices are not structs but elements of slices in Go have very similar semantics to struct fields: they all are considered individual variables in its [memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem).

Comment: @RostyslavKholodnytskyi, note that when you have a variable of a `struct` type, nothing prevents you from taking addresses of its individual fields and operating them via those pointers. For instance, you could have a method `updateStreet` defined on `*Address` (a pointer to `Address`), and call `u.address.updateStreet("whatever")` which would mutate the contents of the `address` field of `u` via a pointer.

Comment: @RostyslavKholodnytskyi: What you use depends heavily on the use-case. Sometimes you _have_ to use a pointer field in a struct, sometimes you don't. Sometimes you want a pointer receiver, sometimes you don't. In this case, having `u` hold a pointer to `a` to me would be code smell. The fact that `updateStreet` alters the value of `u.address`, and implicitly updates the value in `a` would be a side effect, and is generally regarded as bad. It also results in code that isn't safe for concurrent use (data races).

Comment: TL;DR: there's no definitive answer to the question _"which is better for production"_. The answer will always depend on the use case. The only question with a definitive answer given your small example here is: _"would it be safe for concurrent use to have `user.address` be a pointer to `a`?"_, to which the answer is a resounding NO